# C# Not understanding where to go from here

Tags: c#

I have been working on this homework for awhile now i am 2 problems away from being finished... This question particularly is stumping me and im not even sure i understand what its asking... Its late and coffee is wearing off can someone point me in the right direction...

**For all elements in the List letterGrades If the element at index i is equal to grade, then increment noOfGrades by 1. This
comparison should happen regardless of case, i.e., for p/P/f/F.

[Basic front end program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Lprv.jpg)

Here is the current list of code i have so far...

```
/*
 * Calculate letter grades as P for Pass and F for Fail based on the marks obtained.
 * Find the number of instances with the given grades.
 */
namespace Ex1
{
    public partial class LetterGrade : Form
    {
        // Initialize string List
        public List<string> letterGrades = new List<string>();

        public LetterGrade()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


        private void submitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            double marks = double.Parse(marksTextbox.Text); //Declare variable marks and set

            // If statements for marks
            if (marks>0 && marks<=60)
            {
                letterGrades.Add("F");
            }
            else if (marks>60 && marks<=100)
            {
                letterGrades.Add("P");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Not a valid marks");
            }
            marksTextbox.Clear();
        }


        private void calculateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string grade = letterGradeTextbox.Text; // initialize string grade
            int noOfGrades = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < letterGrades.Count; i++)
            {
                if (grade == "P" || grade == "p") //Problem here, step 7a...could not initialize using [i]..tried using a workaround but it keeps total count..
                {
                    noOfGrades++;
                }
                else if (grade == "F" || grade == "f") 
                {
                    noOfGrades++;
                }
            }

            letterGradeTextbox.Clear();

            MessageBox.Show("Number of instances with given letter grade is: " + noOfGrades);
        }
    }
}
```

I am most likely over thinking this to the moon and back but if someone can point me down the right rabbit hole id be super grateful

Comment: The phrase "For all elements in the List letterGrades If the element at index i is equal to grade, then increment noOfGrades by 1" practically reads as code; just convert it into code.

Comment: Now that you've gotten your answer, I'm going to go ahead and close this question, since it is unlikely to ever benefit anyone else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
for (int i = 0; i < letterGrades.Count; i++)
{
    if (letterGrades[i].ToLower() == grade.ToLower())
    {
        noOfGrades++;
    }
}
```

Essentially, for each grade in `letterGrades`, we want to check if that grade equals `grade`, which was entered into `letterGradeTextbox.Text`

Comment: You're seriously going to do his homework problem for him?

Comment: @RobertHarvey No - because it's clear from his comment at that line of code that he has *tried* to do what I've posted, but clearly was missing something in terms of syntax. He has written a workaround in the form of the multiple if-statements.

Comment: Sorry im not meaning to make it sound like i want it done for me... I feel like im over thinking what its asking of me. If its simply asking me to "seek" certain grades i think i might get it

Comment: @KodySnow Here's the process; when `submitButton_Click` is clicked, we store the grade entered into `marksTextbox.Text`. This could happen multiple times, so `letterGrades` could end up with [F,F,P,F,P] - for example. The question is now asking, when the user enters `F` into `letterGradeTextbox.Text` - the result should be `3`. That is, for each item in `letterGrades`, we want to check each item and compare it to `F`. If it matches, then we increase the count.

Comment: @Rob the If statement you provided how does that differ from the if statement i wrote?

Comment: @KodySnow In this *particular* example, there is no logical difference. That's because by reading above, we can see that the only valid grades are `F` and `P`. If, for example, that changed to be A,B,C,D,E,F instead of P,F - then you would need 6 if statements to check. I noticed you need case-insensitivity for the comparison, so please see edit

Comment: @KodySnow: A loop can handle as many cases as needed.  Your approach requires adding a new `if` for each new case.

Comment: @Rob I am still confused am i to replace my if function with yours? It still calculates all F/f/P/p with 0 its not counting them. I feel like im making this way harder then it needs to be

Comment: @KodySnow Did you go through the process of adding grades via the `submitButton` ?

Comment: @Rob that not what i did with this

  private void submitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            double marks = double.Parse(marksTextbox.Text); //Declare variable marks and set

            // If statements for marks
            if (marks>0 && marks<=60)
            {
                letterGrades.Add("F");
            }
            else if (marks>60 && marks<=100)
            {
                letterGrades.Add("P");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Not a valid marks");
            }
            marksTextbox.Clear();
        }

Comment: @KodySnow When running the application, `letterGrades` is empty. On your form, you must manually type in 'P', click `submit`, type in `F`, click `submit`, and so on. After you've done that a few times, type `F` or `P` into `letterGradeTextbox` and click `calculate`.

Comment: @Rob what do you mean by manually put the f and p in? When i run the program and input the letter grade i am always getting zero...